# Restrict generic union type to allow number of types greater then N

Tags: typescript, types, union-types

I haven't found any information on how to restrict the number of union types generic type can accept.

The only partially relevant topic can be found here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298 but still, it's not what I'm targeting to achieve.

Given I have the following code:

```js
enum Currency {
  EUR = "eur",
  USD = "usd",
  PLN = "pln",
  RUB = "rub"
}

type Token<T extends Currency = Currency> = {
  type: T;
  value: string;
};

const token1: Token<Currency.EUR> = {
  type: Currency.EUR,
  value: "1"
}

const token2: Token<Currency.USD> = {
  type: Currency.USD,
  value: "1"
}


const currencies = [token1, token2];

const currencyNonUnion = token1.type; // is Currency.EUR
const currencyUnion = currencies[0].type; // // is Currency.EUR | Currency.USD

// should return never when T is not a union type and forward T in other when it's a union type
// MoreThanOne<Currency.EUR, Currency> // never
// MoreThanOne<Currency.EUR | Currency.ETH, Currency> // Currency.EUR | Currency.ETH
type MoreThanOne<T, R> = T 

const foo = <T>(curr: MoreThanOne<T, Currency>) => { /// }

// should work
foo(currencyUnion);

// shuld fail
foo(currencyNonUnion);
```

([typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=41&ssc=1&pln=41&pc=4#code/KYOwrgtgBAwmBO9QGMCeUDeAoKUCiAqgEpQC8UARMAhQDQ5QEDKAImZWAM4AmdDACgBkAcuwoAHADYg+uIgQBCY+GABGFLAF8sWAC6pxwKABUA9gGtQAHmNRgAD12hunWAiQg07OIhSoAfOzYuPqGAFwmANwMAG4AhpJgwBGcuvAAliAA5tGa0VjIpiCpULoWoACMEWaWIFY+HmgAdIREgeTBpQbJbr6eqC3E9LjxiT0UFRraBUUlZbUATNXldQ1+Tcws7ZgMoT1r-Rusw1CjSRETUzozxbpQyO4o6cCu5ADa85W0pSsLALr5Qq3e6PfrCIoEEDpIrsT4gCpNPaRKAAehRUHSrgOzVaNxKDz6aEh0JA7AJjWenDeAAY-ojusi0aj0Zjeo0Bq0oAAfNnrTY6JmcAAWpjAkm4UCQugQpJAwBiwHgUAA7kLQCYMa4QKY7nEoGAoTC9lA4iAJQAzUzwZVxeAS2yZKA6tVK1Xq9K6ADkrj1BpJXUMWCZAFkrcBjELTQB5OX1UE4oa8-qBJlyhXwIPo0NICPR2PYjnEblJnHGAAS3wLKfRBcGJB5tbw5b03Sg2fDkZAMeANm+bXYth0QJKltM7Bs-gAFOSIu3c13Y8ZK-GAgBKMiBDDM9HTQUisUS5VW8xYUfTlfEoqr-J7g9Qc1xdKSU+mUznwmocEgS8ga9YIA))

`MoreThanOne` generic utility type should return never when it's not a union type.
Given the above requirement second `foo` call should throw a compile-time error.